# Weird javascript behavior when included by php using google chrome

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

In my application (using Zend Framework), I have a layout file (`layout.phtml`) with the `<head>` section including some javascripts this way:

```
<head>
  // Some code
  <?php include('template/javascript.php') ?>
</head>
```

And in the `javascript.php` I have:

```
<?php
  print '<script type="text/javascript; 
    src="'.PASTA_JAVASCRIPT.DS_URL.'jquery'.DS_URL.'jquery.js" ></script>';
  print '<script type="text/javascript; 
    src="'.PASTA_JAVASCRIPT.DS_URL.'application.js" ></script>';
  // More code
```

The thing is, when I use Firefox, all of these scripts are loading correctly and its ready to use. But when using Google Chrome, besides they are being rendered on the html header, I can't use jquery or any other variables I defined on my `application.js`.

One other point I need to mention is that if I remove the php `include` code and manually set the scripts inside the `<head>` tag like the code below, it works like a charm:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="/path/to/my/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

All I could think of is some crazy behavior of Php's `print/echo` or Google Chrome's way of interpreting things... Seriously, I have no idea.
Anyone know what could be possibly causing this behavior?

Comment: Semicolon at the end of the text/JavaScript might b causing this issue.

Comment: Seems like you miss a quote. Also no semicolon allowed in the type attribute. should be `print '<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="'.PASTA_JAVASCRIPT.DS_URL.'application.js" ></script>';`

Comment: @insomiac was right. Weird that it works on firefox. Anyway, if you put your comment as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like semicolon issue..

javascript.php - Try this

```
<?php
      print '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.PASTA_JAVASCRIPT.DS_URL.'jquery'.DS_URL.'jquery.js" ></script>';
      print '<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="'.PASTA_JAVASCRIPT.DS_URL.'application.js" ></script>';
```

Or use echo

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.PASTA_JAVASCRIPT.DS_URL.'jquery'.DS_URL.'jquery.js" ></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" 
            src="'.PASTA_JAVASCRIPT.DS_URL.'application.js" ></script>';
```